# How to get type of a property based on another property in object array?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a simple parser based on rules passed by constructor.
The code works great but there are some type issues.

```js
interface RuleBase {
  parse(text: string, params: Record<string, any>): string;
}

class RuleA implements RuleBase {
  parse(text: string, params: { a: 'aa' }) {
    // parse rules
    return '';
  }
}

class RuleB implements RuleBase {
  parse(text: string, params: { b: 'bb' }) {
    // parse rules
    return '';
  }
}

class Parser<T extends Record<string, RuleBase>> {
  private parserRules: T;

  constructor(parserRules: T) {
    this.parserRules = parserRules;
  }

  parse(text: string, rules: { ruleName: keyof T; params: Parameters<T[keyof T]['parse']>[1] }[]) {
    let result = text;

    rules.forEach(({ ruleName, params }) => {
      const rule = this.parserRules[ruleName];
      if (rule) result = rule.parse(result, params);
    });

    return result;
  }
}
```

Here's the usage code:

```js
const parser = new Parser({
  a: new RuleA(),
  b: new RuleB(),
});

// this is ok (Expected)
parser.parse('Example1', [
  { ruleName: 'a', params: { a: 'aa' } },
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { b: 'bb' } },
]);
parser.parse('Example2', [
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { b: 'bb' } },
]);

// this is not ok. It should throw an error because the rule 'b' only requires the parameter 'b'
parser.parse('Example3', [
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },
]);

// this is not ok. It should throw an error because the rule 'a' only requires the parameter 'a' and the rule 'b' only requires the parameter 'b'
parser.parse('Example4', [
  { ruleName: 'a', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },
]);
```

For the example3 parse(), the rule "b" should only accept { b: 'bb' } for Its params, but { a: 'aa' } or { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } can be used as well which is not intended.

Is there a solution for this without changing the logic of code?
Or, should I change the logic to achieve this?

Comment: In your example you wrote ```params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' }``` does it still not throw an error after removing ```b: 'bb'```? I feel like the code is just ignoring```a: 'aa'``` because only ```b: 'bb'``` is required

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works well but I just hope it to throw a type error when I use like `{ ruleName: 'b', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },` or `{ ruleName: 'b', params: { a: 'aa' } },` because the rule b only needs { b: 'bb' } to parse text.

Comment: I see, I'm sorry but I couldn't come up with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the behavior that's being shown here by the Typescript Compiler is due to how it widens types. The scanner scans and infers that you're creating an array of some type and after checking the type of element the array is going to have, it widens it to add all the possible values for it. For most part, it's ***considered*** that this behavior cannot be overcome, however, that's mostly because this requires writing really nasty types which are pretty specific to a use case. With that being said, this is how you can achieve this -

```ts
interface RuleBase {
  parse(text: string, params: Record<string, any>): string;
}

type Keys<T> = keyof T;

type DiscriminatedUnionOfRecord<
  A,
  B = {
    [Key in keyof A as "_"]: {
      [K in Key]: [
        { [S in K]: A[K] extends A[Exclude<K, Keys<A>>] ? never : A[K] }
      ];
    };
  }["_"]
> = Keys<A> extends Keys<B>
  ? B[Keys<A>] extends Array<any>
  ? B[Keys<A>][number]
  : never
  : never;

type ConstrainedRule<
  T extends Record<string, RuleBase>,
  DU = {
    [Key in DiscriminatedUnionOfRecord<T> as "_"]: {
      [Prop in keyof Key as "_"]: {
        ruleName: Prop;
        params: "parse" extends keyof Key[Prop]
        ? Key[Prop]["parse"] extends (...args: any) => any
        ? Parameters<Key[Prop]["parse"]>[1]
        : never
        : never;
      };
    };
  }["_"]
> = "_" extends keyof DU ? DU["_"][] : never;

class RuleA implements RuleBase {
  parse(text: string, params: { a: 'aa' }) {
    // parse rules
    return '';
  }
}

class RuleB implements RuleBase {
  parse(text: string, params: { b: 'bb' }) {
    // parse rules
    return '';
  }
}

class Parser<T extends Record<string, RuleBase>> {
  private parserRules: T;

  constructor(parserRules: T) {
    this.parserRules = parserRules;
  }

  parse<K extends keyof T>(text: string, rules: ConstrainedRule<T>) {
    let result = text;

    // Need to add this to appease typescript, that's because of the typescript system being static in nature.
    // There's a lot that ConstrainedRule type unpacks, so the typescript infers it as unknown at this point
    (rules as Array<{ ruleName: K, params: Parameters<T[K]['parse']>[1] }>).forEach(({ ruleName, params }) => {
      const rule = this.parserRules[ruleName];
      if (rule) result = rule.parse(result, params);
    });

    return result;
  }
}

const parser = new Parser({
  a: new RuleA(),
  b: new RuleB(),
});

parser.parse('Example1', [
  { ruleName: 'a', params: { a: 'aa' } },
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { b: 'bb' } },
]);
parser.parse('Example2', [
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { b: 'bb' } },
]);

// this is not ok. It should throw an error because the rule 'b' only requires the parameter 'b'
parser.parse('Example3', [
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },
]);

// this is not ok. It should throw an error because the rule 'a' only requires the parameter 'a' and the rule 'b' only requires the parameter 'b'
parser.parse('Example4', [
  { ruleName: 'a', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },
  { ruleName: 'b', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },
]);
```

Essentially, we need to make Typescript scanner not scan and widen the type here. Here's a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m07KxN).

**NOTE**: As I mentioned before, this is pretty specific to your use-case as asked in the question, if there's anything that's different for your, real use case(so to say), it might break.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I still can confirm a type issue with your solution when both rules are passed like:
`parser.parse('A B', [{ ruleName: 'a', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } }, { ruleName: 'b', params: { a: 'aa', b: 'bb' } },]);`

Comment: I didn't know that was a requirement from your question, it's not mentioned anywhere. Consider making an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76856573/edit). I'll update my answer too.

Comment: Ok. I will add an example case of this as well.